# Angular 5: Getting a QueryList for all ContentChildren (even the ones in sub components)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, directive

I have the following html structure where `foo` and `bar` are two directives and `baz` is a custom component.

```
<div foo>
  <div bar></div>
  <baz><baz>
  <baz><baz>
</div>
```

The html of the `baz`-component looks something like ...

```
<div bar>Yada Yada Yada</div>
```

... and the `foo`-directive looks something like this:

```
// ...
@Directive({
  selector: '[foo]'
})
export class FooDirective implements AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChildren(BarDirective)
  m_bars: QueryList<BarDirective>;

  public ngAfterContentInit(): void {

    console.log('barCount:', this.m_bars.length);
  }
}
```

The problem I experience is that the length of `m_bars` inside the `FooDirective` is 1. It only contains the `div` that is a direct child of `<div foo>`. I however expected this number to be 3 (the one direct child of `<div foo>` and the other `div`'s inside the two `baz`-components).

Why is that so and how can this problem be solved - if it can be solved at all?

Edit 1:
Changing the `ContentChildren` decorator to

```
@ContentChildren(BarDirective, { descendants: true })
m_bars: QueryList<BarDirective>;
```

doesn't have any effect at all.

Comment: Check out my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

It's just not possible, which sucks. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20810#issuecomment-401341413 for further information. I'll quote the tl;dr version for reference:

> In short: we only query component's own content, not content coming from other templates. This makes sense since a template forms a namespace #foo in one template might mean one thing and completely different thing in another template. Names might be the same but meaning quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Check this StackBlitz out (watch for console output):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7ybb3

You would have to chain that through outputs. QueryList has an Observable for changes, you could try using it as the output. Something along those lines:

```
@ContentChildren() something: QueryList<Type>;

@Output() queryListChange = new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit() {
    this.something.changes.subscribe(v => {
        this.queryListChange.emit(v);
    }
}
```

And in the upper component you would need to subscribe to this output:

`(queryListChange)="onQueryListChange($event)"`

And in onQueryListChange you would need to merge those items you received with component's own ViewChildren.

And pass it along the same way if more levels of nesting is required.

I don't know a way to merge QueryLists so I just got original array from them and merged those in my stackblitz.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The `QueryList` of the `FooDirective` doesn't change. If i put `this.m_bars.changes.subscribe(i => console.log(i.length));` inside `ngAfterContentInit()` it won't output anything. And i'd prefer not to tinker with the `baz`-components source code just to bubble all it's children (that have a `bar`-directive) somehow into `m_bars`.

Comment: It does change, just not in the order you expect and you will for sure have to tinker with baz component source code since you try to overcome a limitation (a reasonable one if you ask me) of not being able to reach from one thing into other thing's area of concern. I'll try to make a stackblitz for you if I have time.